# Register user when after filling contact form

Tags: users, user-registration

Is there any wordpress plugin with the following functionality.

Let say that I have a contact form with the following fields: Name, email, file upload, textarea and ect.

When the user fill the form and send it, the admin receive email with the information. After that a user profile is automaticaly created from the email and random password is generated.

After sending the form the user receive on his email the login details.

Basically the admin receive the details from the contact form and the plugin automaticaly generate username(from the filled email in the form) and generate random password.